# getDelegate() method inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-night-mode

I want to turn on the night Mode in android Fragment.

The code runs fine in the activity `getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`

But we cannot use the same code inside the fragment

What is the solution of this?

Is there any alternative way of turning on the nightmode inside the fragment?

[image: Error in the fragment]

The code:                    `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

The above code refreshes the fragment and the fragment as well as the parent activity

Comment: You can reference the activity from the fragment

Comment: Can you explain how? Post your answer sir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`

Comment: The above code closes the fragment as well as the parent activity.please check the edits sir

Answer (score 0):

You can also start this in fragment with kotlin like so:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
   ....
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.delegate.localNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
.....

}
```

normally you store values in shared preferences and then switch modes from an ui event